# How to preview URL in bottom of browser when hovering over element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

For a normal hyperlink, you can hover over a link and you will see a preview of the URL in the bottom left of the browser window. 
[image: Example with hyperlink]

For my purposes, I want to make it so you can hover over any arbitrary element (perhaps a button) and then have it preview the URL in the bottom of the window. Would this be possible, and if so, how? I have not found any solutions for this yet, but there could be something I am overlooking.

```html
<a href="https://google.com">This has a preview effect</a><br><br><br>
<button onclick="window.location='https://google.com';">This needs a preview effect</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the button with `<a>` tags?

Comment: Don't wrap your button with an `<a>` tag. It's not semantic and will result in errors in your validation test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to add this URL preview to any element manually. It would be a big security issue since the URL preview can be used to determine if a URL is legit or not trustable before even visiting the page.

You can use the `title` attribute to show a label on hover.

Comment: That's a very good point! And a good solution as well. Thank you!

Comment: @Pangamma thanks, there are also several Javascript solutions for tooltips if you want to change the style, position or behaviour of the title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

That's a browser implementation.

Anchor tags are your best option

You can wrap an anchor tag around the button tag

```
<a href="https://google.com">This has a preview effect</a><br>
<a href="https://othergoogle.com"><button>This needs a preview effect</button></a>
```

This is not your best option though.

Your best option is to style the anchor tag as you please.

Use ids and classes to target the elements from CSS and style them as you please.

For the end user there's really no difference when looking at a styled anchor tag that looks like a button or a button that is wrapped by an anchor tag.

Hope this helps you.